# Can AD FS 3.0 (ADFS 3.0) Authenticate a user against a custom (non-ldap) store?

Tags: active-directory, adfs3.0

As I read the documentation, ADFS 3.0 can only use ldap authentication stores.

The IAuthenticationAdapter (in Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.dll) can only be used as secondary authentication for a user existing in an ldap store.

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADFS 3,0 can only authenticate against AD; not against any LDAP (although that feature is coming in ADFS vNext (ADFS 4.0?).

Refer - [How to create a Custom Authentication Provider for Active Directory Federation Services on Windows Server 2012 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2014/01/30/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0-part-1.aspx)  as an example of a secondary MFS provider.

Comment: Your link is 404 now. I _guess_ that [this one might](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-build-custom-auth-method) be the correct link now. Unfortunately I found [no Archive.org entry](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0-part-1) for your link.